# Autodesk.Forge.DerivativesApi.GetManifest(urn) failed status

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there any way to determine why a particular translation failed?   I am processing a decent sized NWD file (262MB) that has translated successfully in the past, but is now failing.  I can convert a smaller NWD file with no issues.    The GetManifest result has a progress of "complete" but a status of "failed" - no other information that will help me diagnose the underlying translation issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Model Derivative service supports over 60 different file formats where each format's translation can fail for different reasons, with varying amount of explanation as to why it failed. That's why, unfortunately, the translations can sometimes fail without providing any helpful information, or just with some arbitrary error code number. In those cases we'd ask you to share the file with us (confidentially, the file would not be shared outside of Autodesk) via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, so that we can debug the translation on our end.

Comment: It is a rather large file (262MB) so what is the best way to get it to you?

Comment: Also, follow up question, is it possible that the GetManifest call would refurn failed if we hit some sort of API request limit (per file, per minute, etc.)?    Once we submit the file for translation, we poll and check for the status using the GetManifest method.

Comment: I'd suggest zipping the file and sharing it via one of the cloud storage provides like Google Drive or OneDrive.

Comment: And regarding the rate limits, the Model Derivative does limit requests to [certain endpoints](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/rate-limiting/md-rate-limits/), but as far as I know, GetManifest is not one of them.